# Can function get empty arguments?

Tags: fish

My code

```
function foo
    argparse -n foo 'u/user=' 'g/group=' 's/shell=' -- $argv

    bar $_flag_u $_flag_g $_flag_s
end

function bar -a user group shell
    echo $user
    echo $group
    echo $shell
end

foo $argv
```

Execute and Result

```
> fish test.fish -u user_name -g group_name -s shell_name
user_name
group_name
shell_name
> fish test.fish -g group_name -s shell_name
group_name
shell_name

> fish test.fish -u user_name -s shell_name
user_name
shell_name

>
```

Expectation I want

```
> fish test.fish -u user_name -g group_name -s shell_name
user_name
group_name
shell_name
> fish test.fish -g group_name -s shell_name

group_name
shell_name
> fish test.fish -u user_name -s shell_name
user_name

shell_name
>
```

Can I get the expectation?
If -u option is not used, my expectation is that $user in bar function is empty.
 (it means that result of "echo $status" is 1 after "set -q user".)

If I have no choice, I'll do bellow:
(Reference: https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/3926)

```
function foo
    argparse -n foo 'u/user=' 'g/group=' 's/shell=' -- $argv

    set -q _flag_u; or set _flag_u ''
    set -q _flag_g; or set _flag_g ''
    set -q _flag_s; or set _flag_s ''

    bar $_flag_u $_flag_g $_flag_s
end

function bar -a user group shell

    if test -n $user
        # do something
    end
    if test -n $group
        # do something
    end
    if test -n $shell
        # do something
    end
end

foo $argv
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is this:

```
function bar -a user group shell
```

This means bar calls its first argument "user", the second "group" and the third "shell".

When you then run

```
bar $u $g $s
```

fish expands the variables. If they are set, they'll expand to as many arguments as they have elements (in fish, all variables are lists!).

So you'll get $u into $user, $g into $group and $s into $shell.

However, if one isn't set (because the option wasn't given in the call to `foo`), then the variable will expand to nothing, so if e.g. `--group` wasn't given, this works like

```
bar $u $s
```

which will assign the contents of $u to $user and $s to $group - because it is the second argument that bar sees.

To inhibit this, either use `set -q` or double-quote the variable:

```
    bar "$_flag_u" "$_flag_g" "$_flag_s"
```

Comment: Thank you  for your comment !  I understand fish's mechanism. And, your proposal, using "double-quote" looks good for my case. Thanks again.